# Redirecting Arduino Serial Output to a File

Tags: arduino-uno

I am integrating the MPU-6050 Accelerometer + Gyro sensor into a large project that contains 12 Arduino boards and 6 Raspberry Pis. At some point, I will have to load the output of my MPU-6050 sensor into another application through command line. The process is to be all done with Python and Bash (on the Raspberry Pi side), and so what I need is a way to store the output of my Arduino boards.

What I am currently looking at is the python program `ino`. I have used the product for about a year now, and as far as I am aware of, the only way to exit out of serial mode in `ino` is by closing the command-line window!

Is there a way I can achieve what I've discussed above? Essentially, all I want is a way to hold the output of my Arduino serial output so I can use it later in other parts of my project.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to store the data recorded from an Arduino Uno through serial on a Raspberry Pi?

Comment: not necessarily the Pi, but in my case, yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I don't know about your `ino` program, but here's how I'd do it:

get_serial.py

```
import serial, sys

with serial.Serial(port=sys.argv[1], baudrate=sys.argv[2]) as ser:
    while ser.isOpen():
        print(ser.readline())
```

The idea, here, is to print on `stdout` the data coming on the serial line:

```
python get_serial.py /dev/ttyACM0 115200 > output.log
```

or you can do it this way:

get_serial.py

```
import serial, sys

with open(sys.argv[3]) as f:
    with serial.Serial(port=sys.argv[1], baudrate=sys.argv[2]) as ser:
        while ser.isOpen():
            f.write(ser.readline())
```

which is ran:

```
python get_serial.py /dev/ttyACM0 115200 output.log
```

Hope this helps!